# How to use aws cognito hosted ui to my xamarin .net androidbapp development

Tags: xamarin.android, amazon-cognito

I am planning to use default aws cognito hosted ui to my android application . I can redirect to login/reg page from my application using "webview' feature .
However is there any way to navigate back to my application with client I'd when the login is successful ?

Comment: Yes, Pass your own URL in caQllback url and it redirect to it post success.